# Tokens for multi-valued fields?

Tags: 7, tokens

In D7, it seems the token for fields (e.g., `[node:field_date]`) just returns the rendering of the field. So if the field is multi-valued, this token returns all the values rendered together. However, I'd like to be able to access specific delta values of the field separately using tokens, e.g. using `[node:field_date:0]` or similar syntax. I also want to be able to chain the token, e.g. `[node:field_date:0:long]`.

Has this been done before? My solution would be to use `hook_token_info_alter` to mark the field's token as `dynamic`, then do my own parsing in `hook_tokens_alter`. But if I do this, will I lose the ability to chain the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Entity Tokens? It's part of [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module.

There are long discussions about date tokens: [Date issue](http://drupal.org/node/1103032) about date tokens and [Entity Token issue](http://drupal.org/node/1058856) about multi-value field tokens.

Comment: It seems it does require the patch from https://www.drupal.org/node/2126215 to get it work, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

For Date fields there are 3 available values to use...

```
[node:field-date:value]    = Start date
[node:field-date:value2]   = End date
[node:field-date:duration] = Well... Duration. :-)
```

/marcus

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. In a multi-valued field_date, I'd like to access value 1, value 2, value 3, etc.

Comment: Sorry. Then I would assume that something like [node:field_foo:value:?] where ? is the Delta. But it seems to only work for taxonomy term parents... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to use the [Compound Token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/compound_token) for this.

Works with vanilla Token:

```
[node:field_my_field]
```

Throws errors with vanilla Token; Works after installing Compound Token:

```
[node:field_my_field:und:0:value]
```